# Blob data for PNG

Tags: php

im working with a lib, exstending on it, and i have this method that checks if data is a Media

```
function isMedia($blob) {
    // Check for a JPG header.
    if ($blob[0] == chr(0xFF) && $blob[1] == chr(0xD8)) {
      return TRUE;
    }

    // Check for a MP4 header.
    if ($blob[0] == chr(0x00) && $blob[1] == chr(0x00)) {
      return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
  }
```

Im not that good with Blob data, i understand that it checks the first part of the data for special encoding, how would i check for PNG ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would normally recommend you use PHP's built in image detection stuff from GD or ImageMagick but I assume you have a good reason. So to check for PNG header you need to make sure the first part of the blob matches (according to http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html)

```
89  50  4e  47  0d  0a  1a  0a
```

So something like

```
// Is PNG
if (
    $blob[0] == chr(0x89) &&
    $blob[1] == chr(0x50) &&
    $blob[2] == chr(0x4e) &&
    $blob[3] == chr(0x47) &&
    $blob[4] == chr(0x0d) &&
    $blob[5] == chr(0x0a) &&
    $blob[6] == chr(0x1a) &&
    $blob[7] == chr(0x0a)
   ) {
     // Yes
}
```

I haven't tested the above code so there may be slight errors but you can use it as a bases but it should work ;)

Comment: Thanks, and yes this is a lib i have running, wanted to exstend it to allow .PNG didnt want to change the basic methods :)

Comment: You may be able to leave out part of those checks, I don't readily have a PNG blob to test, but I think most of the image types have vastly different file signatures.

Comment: You can probably use `strpos`: `if (0 === strpos($blob, "\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n")) { print "PNG!"; }`. (Beware the three ='s).

Answer (score 0):

The best way, if you have a recent PHP and can do it (otherwise, see Steven's solution) is to use [`fileinfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-buffer.php) and let `libmagic` (nothing to do with ImageMagick) do its magic:

```
function isMedia($blob) {
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $accepted_types = array(
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/png',
        'video/mp4',
    );
    $mime = $finfo->buffer($blob);
    return in_array($mime, $accepted_types);
}
```

Actually, if you are only interested in telling audio and video media from others, you can also do:

```
list($broad,) = explode('/', $mime); // get the "image" from "image/png"
return (('video' == $broad) || ('image' == $broad));
```

MIME for [video/mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277147/m4v-mimetype-video-mp4-or-video-m4v). Other MIME types [here](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml).

Comment: That is probably a better way, I would much rather let a C library find the image type then file -> blob -> read blob with php -> look for parts of blob. Plus it would most likely be faster... For others `libmagic` is `file` or at least parts of it in a C library.