# m4v video not working in chrome

Tags: html, video

I am using html5 video tag for playing third party m4v videos(like https://pelpresenterdev.blob.core.windows.net/pellapresenterdev01/d41991d0-3b45-42cb-914d-26dc01297ca8.m4v). This is not playing in chrome and safari,while using local m4v videos it is working fine.But in both case it is working successfully in firefox.I think the problem is with third party m4v video. 
Please give your ideas.
Below is my code

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay><source src="https://pelpresenterdev.blob.core.windows.net/pellapresenterdev01/d41991d0-3b45-42cb-914d-26dc01297ca8.m4v" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: your biggest challenge with HTML5 video will be preparing and incorporating your content in multiple codecs. Currently, each browser has its own preferred video format. And it appears that the fractured implementation of HTML5 video will get worse before it gets better. Have a look [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/html5-audio-and-video-firefox).

Comment: yes Ashish,i got your point. Is there any generic solution? so that i can suggest my customers to upload a particular format.

Comment: If you're asking for a particular format than I'd suggest mp4. But if you're not specific to a format than you can go for that solution.

Answer (score 1):

Could be the Codec encoding of the video. I found a video encoded as MPEG-4 didn't display in Chrome - but a video encoded with the Codec of H.264 did.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" preload="none">
  <!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, Android and Others -->
  <source type="video/mp4" src="https://pelpresenterdev.blob.core.windows.net/pellapresenterdev01/d41991d0-3b45-42cb-914d-26dc01297ca8.mp4" />

  <!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
  <source type="video/webm" src="https://pelpresenterdev.blob.core.windows.net/pellapresenterdev01/d41991d0-3b45-42cb-914d-26dc01297ca8.webm" />

   <!-- M4V for Apple -->
  <source type="video/mp4" src="https://pelpresenterdev.blob.core.windows.net/pellapresenterdev01/d41991d0-3b45-42cb-914d-26dc01297ca8.m4v" />

  <!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
  <source type="video/ogg" src="https://pelpresenterdev.blob.core.windows.net/pellapresenterdev01/d41991d0-3b45-42cb-914d-26dc01297ca8.ogv" />

  <!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->
  <object width="100%" height="400" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashmediaelement.swf">
      <param name="movie" value="flashmediaelement.swf" />
      <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=https://pelpresenterdev.blob.core.windows.net/pellapresenterdev01/d41991d0-3b45-42cb-914d-26dc01297ca8.mp4" />
  </object>
</video>
```

Also you should refer [mark4o's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15279480/5588347). He explains Apple started using their own media type, video/x-m4v, for videos from their store, which are in an mp4 container and use a .m4v extension. This is set to open the video in iTunes by default. Sometimes that is necessary because the video uses DRM, AC-3 Dolby Digital audio, or other capabilities that are not commonly supported in an mp4 container, but which are supported by iTunes for files with a .m4v extension. If you rely on such capabilities then you may want to use this media type instead of the standard one.

As [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-cross-browser-video-playback-in-html5/) says:

Keep the following fixes in mind if you’re having trouble implementing  on your website:

- The MP4 version of the video must be listed first because of a bug in the iPad. In this case you can do like this:

  ```
  <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" preload="none">
   <!-- M4V for Apple -->
   <source type="video/mp4" src="https://pelpresenterdev.blob.core.windows.net/pellapresenterdev01/d41991d0-3b45-42cb-914d-26dc01297ca8.m4v" />

        //remaining code
    </video>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't work because https://pelpresenterdev.blob.core.windows.net/pellapresenterdev01/d41991d0-3b45-42cb-914d-26dc01297ca8.m4v returns an XML which states "The specified blob does not exist."